# Changing the CSS of a div that's containing an input form

Tags: html, css

All i want to do is change the border of "apps-search" when you focus on the the "input. 
And i'd like to do it using just CSS.

Help? thank you :)

```
<form class="apps-search" type="text"  method="GET">
   <input name="search_query" id="search_query" placeholder="Hey" />
<button type="submit"> <span class="search-icon"> S</span></button>
</form>
```

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/yhQ2C/

EDIT: Ok so this can't be done in CSS, jquery/javascript help?

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS.  Theres no way to fall backwards in CSS when you are referencing items.  In other words, you can't go .apps-search > input .apps-search  (or move from 1 to 2 then back to 1)

Comment: `apps-search` is not a `div`.

Comment: Ok, good to know about CSS not falling backwards.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to setup 2 css classes (i.e **apps-search** & **app-search-black-border**)

Then, use some basic jquery to make the switch.  Here's an article that explains what you need to do:
http://buildinternet.com/2009/01/changing-form-input-styles-on-focus-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

I added some jquery handlers for focus and blur and a sample css class 'hover-border'. Here's the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yhQ2C/4/

```
$('#search_query').focus(function(){
    $('.apps-search').addClass('hover-border');
});

$('#search_query').blur(function(){
    $('.apps-search').removeClass('hover-border');
});
```